# In action script 3, how can I dynamically include a file with certain name, based on a value of another variable?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, include

I have a variable "level", and based on the value of that Number variable, I want a file included, with my level settings for THAT particular level. Level files are called "Level1Definition.as", "Level2Definition.as", "Level3Definition.as", and so on. When I try to form that line of code like this:

```
include "Level" + level + "Definition.as";
```

, I get an error:

```
Expecting semicolon before plus.
```

How can I include file whose name (name of the file) is formed using a variable, during runtime?

Comment: @WillTower The question is
how can I include file whose name (name of the file) is formed using a variable?
(I edited the original question, although it's very clear in the title of the question).

Comment: I want different file to be included at different point (time point, so, basically, moment) in the game. Purpose is that I want to generate levels based on these individual files. So, I want to include them at different moment in the game. So this moment is never in compile time, if you think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ActionScript, you can define an Interface, which essentially says "these are the methods and properties that this type of object will always have." Interfaces are great for allowing you to create really flexible implementations without the code that uses the implementations having to know about the internals. One advantage of not having to know about the internals is that that knowledge does not need to be compiled into the calling code.

If it makes sense for your application to load code that's compiled, using Interfaces really frees you up to do whatever you want in the implementation and have as many of them as you need down the road. [Here's an answer where I talk more about this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645954/whats-the-reason-for-interface-to-exist-in-actionscript-3-and-other-languages/15647800#15647800)

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't work, because the include statement is executed before/during compilation, but the value of your variable determined at runtime.

The core of your problem is that you mix data with logic. You should not have different classes for individual levels. Instead, create one level class that represents a general level object. Create instances of that class and pass the data specific to that level to the object. This data is usually loaded at runtime from a file or server, then deserialized (from json, XML or whatever format is used) before it is used. Hard coding large amounts of data as you do it if not recommended. It also makes it necessary to recompile everything when a level is changed.

Comment: You could also do it by having your different levels implement an Interface and compile each into a swf that you load at runtime.

Comment: @Amy Blankenship why not post this as an answer? If the levels differ substantially in functionality, this can be a better solution.